# XML Element with attribute and CDATA How to retrieve b both using JAXB in Eclipse

Tags: java, jaxb

A section element of XML includes an attribute and CDATA:

```
        ELEM: nodeName="ConfigData" local="ConfigData"
            ATTR: nodeName="ConfigSize" local="ConfigSize" nodeValue="356"
              TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue="356"
          TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue=[WS]
          ELEM: nodeName="Data" local="Data"
              ATTR: nodeName="Format" local="Format" nodeValue="L5K"
                TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue="L5K"
            TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue=[WS]
            CDATA: nodeName="#cdata-section" nodeValue="[360,0,6,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
            TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue=[WS]
          TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue=[WS]
        TEXT: nodeName="#text" nodeValue=[WS]
```

I have used the following code but it could not fetch the CDATA.
@XmlRootElement(name="ConfigData")

```
public class ConfigData {

  private int configSize;
  private Data data;

  @XmlElement(name="Data")
  public void setData(Data data) {  
    this.data = data;  
  } 
  public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Data")

public class Data {

  private String format;
  private String cData;

  @XmlAttribute(name="Format")
    public void setFormat(String format) {
    this.format = format;
    }
  public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

  @XmlCDATA()
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=AdapterXmlCDATA.class)
  public void setCData(String cData) {  
    this.cData = cData;  
  }  
  public String getCData() {  
    return cData;  
  }  
}

public class AdapterXmlCDATA extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String value) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + value + "]]>";
    }
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
      //System.out.println("AdapterXmlCDATA:" + value);
      return value;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. I am thinking that if using a right CDATA notation in the Data Class like "@XmlCDATA()
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=AdapterXmlCDATA.class)" can make it work. Thanks

Comment: What the hell is @XmlCDATA()? What is the import declaration of the fully qualified name for it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is thinking that CDATA sections are somehow special and that their content can be told apart from surrounding text.

In other words, when you have this:

```
<stuff>Hello <![CDATA[Everyone is in the place! ]]>Goodbye</stuff>
```

You think you can extract the String "Hello ", and another String "Everyone is in the place! " and yet another String "Goodbye".

That is not the case. You cannot do that, and you must forget about trying to do it.

The above markup is 100% the same thing as this markup:

```
<stuff>Hello Everyone is in the place! Goodbye</stuff>
```

As you can see, it is impossible to identify what may or may not have been in a CDATA section in the original markup, because when you're trying to use the XML, CDATA sections don't exist at all. CDATA sections are just a syntax tool for when you want to write weird text that you don't want to constantly escape, such as

```
<![CDATA[ <<<<<< &&& Yeah! &&& >>>>>> ]]>
```

which is clearer than

```
&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; &amp;&amp;&amp; Yeah! &amp;&amp;&amp; &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;
```

Yet exactly the same thing in XML.

Bottomline: You cannot get the content of the CDATA section. As far as XML reading is concerned, it doesn't exist. You can only get the entirety of the text in `<Data>`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please explain how I can retrieve both attribute and CDATA? I tried the following way, but I can only get the CDATA out, and the attribute is left out. Maybe it cannot be String type?
@XmlRootElement(name="ConfigData")

public class ConfigData {

```
private int configSize;

private String data;

@XmlElement(name="Data")
public void setData(String data) {  
    System.out.println("ConfigData:" + data);
    this.data = data;  
} 
public String getData() {
    return data;
}
```